# Eclipse SDK 3.2.0 JAVA to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle

Eclipse SDK 3.2.0 JAVA to Oracle 11g Stored Procedure.
I am trying to call a stored procedure and return the output.

My code is below.

The error message I receive is `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

#### Java code snippet:

```
ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("set serveroutput on size unlimited VARIABLE VAR_CV_1 REFCURSOR; execute SP_FAM_VOLWEEKLY(CV_1=> :VAR_CV_1,p_report_type=>0,p_type => 2,p_num_week =>5,P_GROUPBY_GROUP =>1,p_groupby_cpty  =>0,p_groupby_desk =>0,p_groupby_ccy =>1,p_groupby_t_tz =>1,P_GROUPBY_U_LOCALE=>1);PRINT VAR_CV_1;");

while (rs2.next()) {       
    if (rs != null && rs2.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs2.getString("CCY"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code should do? This looks like you're executing a PL/SQL script via a JDBC, and at the end you're printing soumething to the `STDOUT` of your database server. This is not how you call a stored procedure / function from JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

`set serveroutput` is a SQLplus statement that's neither part of Oracle's SQL nor of PL/SQL. So it's not available in the environment (Java Client, OJDBC, Oracle server) that you're using.

The same is the case for `EXECUTE`, `VARIABLE`, `PRINT`.

Furthermore, you cannot execute several statements at once unless you switch from SQL to PL/SQL using a BEGIN/END block.

**Update:**

You're probably looking for code like this:

```
String query = "begin SP_FAM_VOLWEEKLY(CV_1 => ?, p_report_type=> 0, p_type => 2, p_num_week => 5, P_GROUPBY_GROUP => 1, p_groupby_cpty  => 0, p_groupby_desk => 0,  p_groupby_ccy => 1, p_groupby_t_tz => 1, P_GROUPBY_U_LOCALE => 1); end;";

CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);

// register the type of the out param
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

stmt.execute();
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(1);


while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("CCY"))
}
```

Comment: It works from Toad and SQL Developer run manually using the 'Execute as script' option

Comment: SQL Developer implements the full set of SQLplus commands. And Toad runs it using SQLplus in the background (that's the purpose of the *Execute as script* option).